# Vlookup function taking too much time to run when I have more than 100k rows of data:

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the vlookup function in my vba code, but it's taking too much time to run when I have more then 300k rows of data:

I've tried in several ways to optimize the code, however, I am not successful in excel 2016 64bits, corei7 6cores.

I've read here on the forum something about Vba Dictionaries and ARRAYS, but I have not studied on that, and can't understand about it, i need some guides to understand the concepts correctly to implement the solution on my code

```
Sub BuscarDataBancosV6OK()
Dim cel As Range


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False


Range("U:U").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
Range("V:V").NumberFormat = "General"
Range("W:Z").NumberFormat = "0.00"

For Each cel In Selection 'Range(rng) Los datos de bancos a datos generales

'validar si la celda fechaBANCO tiene información, si tiene INFO pasar al siguiente porque ya procesó anteriormente
If cel.Offset(, 16) = "" Then
    GoTo Validarinfo
Else
    GoTo SIGUIENTE
End If

Validarinfo:

Validador = Application.VLookup(cel.Offset(, -4), Workbooks("PRUEBAS DATOS BANCO GRANDES VER2.xlsm").Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A2:M242000"), 1, False)

If IsError(Validador) Then
    cel.Offset(, 34) = "NO CONCILIADO"
    GoTo SIGUIENTE
Else
    'valor bancos
            cel.Offset(, 9).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=+VLOOKUP(RC[-13],'[PRUEBAS DATOS BANCO GRANDES VER2.xlsm]Hoja1'!R2C1:R241666C13,8,FALSE)"
            cel.Offset(, 9) = cel.Offset(, 9).Value
    'fecha acreditación
            cel.Offset(, 16).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=+VLOOKUP(RC[-20],'[PRUEBAS DATOS BANCO GRANDES VER2.xlsm]Hoja1'!R2C1:R241666C13,5,FALSE)"
            cel.Offset(, 16) = cel.Offset(, 16).Value
    'Nombre banco
            cel.Offset(, 17).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=+VLOOKUP(RC[-21],'[PRUEBAS DATOS BANCO GRANDES VER2.xlsm]Hoja1'!R2C1:R241666C13,13,FALSE)"
            cel.Offset(, 17) = cel.Offset(, 17).Value
    'Comisión banco
            cel.Offset(, 18).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=+VLOOKUP(RC[-22],'[PRUEBAS DATOS BANCO GRANDES VER2.xlsm]Hoja1'!R2C1:R241666C13,9,FALSE)"
            cel.Offset(, 18) = cel.Offset(, 18).Value
    'Retención IVA banco
            cel.Offset(, 19).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=+VLOOKUP(RC[-23],'[PRUEBAS DATOS BANCO GRANDES VER2.xlsm]Hoja1'!R2C1:R241666C13,10,FALSE)"
            cel.Offset(, 19) = cel.Offset(, 19).Value
    'Retención IVA renta
            cel.Offset(, 20).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=+VLOOKUP(RC[-24],'[PRUEBAS DATOS BANCO GRANDES VER2.xlsm]Hoja1'!R2C1:R241666C13,11,FALSE)"
            cel.Offset(, 20) = cel.Offset(, 20).Value
    'Valor acreditado banco
            cel.Offset(, 21).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=+VLOOKUP(RC[-25],'[PRUEBAS DATOS BANCO GRANDES VER2.xlsm]Hoja1'!R2C1:R241666C13,12,FALSE)"
            cel.Offset(, 21) = cel.Offset(, 21).Value
    'Status conciliación
            cel.Offset(, 34) = "CONCILIADO"
End If

SIGUIENTE:
    Next cel

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Also, there is no duplicate data in woorkbook PRUEBAS DATOS BANCO GRANDES VER2.xlsm IN "A" COLUMN

Could anyone please help me convert vlookup to dictionary and if possible reference some videos tutorials so I can learn the concept?

Comment: One thing you could do is storing your data into an array and operating on the array in memory instead of operating directly on the Worksheet.
Also keep in mind that VBA in Excel does not use multiple cores only one, so it doesn't matter how many cores your CPU has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be a bit challenging to demonstrate a a dictionary/array solution without having your workbook. I'll show a simple example that I hope demonstrates how this solution would work for you. In all tests I've done, it's significantly faster than looping and using VLOOKUPs.

If you have questions, write back.

The lookup data schema in my test example is (Id, Value1, Value2)

[image: Sample data]

```
Option Explicit

Sub PerformALotOfLookups()
    Dim oDict As Object
    Dim lookupRange As Range
    Dim iterator As Range

    'Dimension of the array should be the number of values you
    'want to store to correspond to the key.
    'In my example, 0 to 1 means there are two values,
    'a 0th value and a 1st value
    Dim arrayOfValues(0 To 1) As Variant

    'The range that we normally vlookup against (only
    'using the first column in my range)
    Set lookupRange = Sheet1.Range("A1:A500")

    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'Set optimization settings
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each iterator In lookupRange
        'Check if the ID already exists
        If Not oDict.exists(iterator.Value) Then
            'create the array
            '0th element is the first column to right of iterator
            arrayOfValues(0) = iterator.Offset(, 1).Value

            '1st element is the second column to right of iterator
            arrayOfValues(1) = iterator.Offset(, 2).Value

            'Add key and array to the dictionary
            oDict.Add iterator.Value, arrayOfValues
        End If
    Next iterator

    ''' Now the dictioary exists, and you can query it by key value
    ''' and return a 2 element array. Access elements by index

    ''Example: Lookup value 5
    ''Show a message box for the 0th element
    ''then show a messagebox for the 1st element
    If oDict.exists(5) Then
        MsgBox oDict(5)(0)
        MsgBox oDict(5)(1)
    End If

    ''Example: Lookup value 37
    ''Show a message box for the 0th element
    ''then show a messagebox for the 1st element
    If oDict.exists(37) Then
        MsgBox oDict(37)(0)
        MsgBox oDict(37)(1)
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is very awesome how runs your code in less than 3 secs. Works fine, but i try inside the same sheet. And i trying working with another sheet but it doesnt works. Could you help me please to adapt it? I post a new comment with your code "adapted" to me.